# Cannot parse UTC date in Athena

Tags: amazon-web-services, datetime-format, amazon-athena, presto, trino

I have the date string in the form: 2019-02-18 09:17:31.260000+00:00 and I am trying to convert it into date in Athena.

I have tried converting into timestamp as suggested in the SO answers but failed.
There is a discussion in https://github.com/prestodb/presto/issues/10567 but no answer to this particular date format.

I tried several format like 'YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSZ' but doesn't work and get error like INVALID_FUNCTION_ARGUMENT: Invalid format:..is malformed at "+00:00".

Been stuck for a while, any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Athena is based on a very old version of Presto, and there is no straightforwad way of doing that with some string manipulation trick. For instance, you can use [`regexp_replace`](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/regexp.html#regexp_replace) to extract the part of the string that's compatible with the built-in timestamp with timezone type and do:

```sql
SELECT cast(regexp_replace('2019-02-18 09:17:31.260000+00:00','(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{3})\d{3}(.*)', '$1$2') AS timestamp with time zone)
```

Recent versions of [Trino](https://trino.io/) ([formerly known as PrestoSQL](https://trino.io/blog/2020/12/27/announcing-trino.html)) introduced support for variable-precision temporal types with up to nanosecond precision (12 decimals).

With that feature, you can just do:

```
trino> select cast('2019-02-18 09:17:31.260000+00:00' as timestamp(6) with time zone);
             _col0
--------------------------------
 2019-02-18 09:17:31.260000 UTC
(1 row)
```

Comment: The first one works :) +1 Thank you so much! However the second one results in error: mismatched input 'with' expecting {')', 'array'} with status code 400.. maybe like you said Athena based on older version of Presto doesn't support it.

Answer (score 1):

A shorter version to [Martin Traverso](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2958752/martin-traverso)'s answer is to sub string the extra characters:

```
select cast(substr('2019-02-18 09:17:31.260000+00:00',1,23) as timestamp);
```

Comment: Thanks for this approach! Yeah its shorter and more readable.

Comment: That works only if you don't care about the timezone, though.